# Python curses blink function doesn't work in gnome-terminal

Tags: python, ncurses, curses

I am using the python curses library. I am trying to make an asterisk blink using this code `win.addstr(6, 4, "*", curses.A_BLINK)` However it does not work on gnome terminal. I tried using it on xterm and it works. It also does not work on the recovery shell. How can I make text blink using the curses library or some other method?

Comment: gnome-terminal supports blinking text since version 3.28.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *could* make a program (whether with curses or even hardcoded) that draws text on the screen and overwrites it with blanks, with a suitable time delay (if it's too short, it annoys people — see PuTTY for an example of *that*).

The drawback is that it would "blink" only as long as the program runs, and of course it's a little complicated.

As a shell script, you could do this:

- save the `stty` settings,
- change the `stty` settings to prevent output of carriage return (**`\r`**) from being converted to **`\r\n`**
- print the text, ended with **`\r`**
- wait a while, e.g., `sleep 1`
- print blanks where you wrote text
- wait a while
- loop back to the first "print"
- on exit, restore the `stty` settings.

For a curses application - you could make it "blink" by replacing the text, in a similar way.  For what it's worth, the **xmas** example in [ncurses-examples](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses-examples.html) uses a combination of window copying and terminal blinking for its animation effects (see [C blinkit](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/ncurses-snapshots/blob/999283215c3e32173c97f62b8bc8a275513ca1ab/test/xmas.c#L444) function and [Python translation](https://github.com/xbmc/python/blob/master/Demo/curses/xmas.py#L272)).